# RecursionError, maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object, what is this error?

Tags: python

```
import pygame
import os
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2-5, 0, 10, HEIGHT)

HEALTH_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 40)
WINNER_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 100)

REDhealth = 15
YELLOWhealth = 15
YELLOWbullets = []
REDbullets = []
FPS = 60
VEL = 5
BULLETspeed = 7
BULLETnum = 4
YELLOWhit = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
REDhit = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
SHIPWIDTH, SHIPHEIGHT = 55, 40
red = pygame.Rect(700, 220, SHIPWIDTH, SHIPHEIGHT)
yellow = pygame.Rect(100, 220, SHIPWIDTH, SHIPHEIGHT)

YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Downloads', 'Heggo.png'))
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SHIPWIDTH, SHIPHEIGHT)), 270)

RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Downloads', 'spaceship_red.png'))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SHIPWIDTH, SHIPHEIGHT)), 270)

BACKGROUND = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Downloads', 'Space.jpeg')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
BACKGROUND = pygame.transform.rotate(BACKGROUND, 180)

def draw_window(red, yellow, REDbullets, YELLOWbullets, REDhealth, YELLOWhealth):
    WIN.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, BORDER)
    
    red_health_text = HEALTH_FONT.render(
        "Health: " + str(REDhealth), 1, WHITE)
    yellow_health_text = HEALTH_FONT.render(
        "Health: " + str(YELLOWhealth), 1, WHITE)
    WIN.blit(red_health_text, (WIDTH - red_health_text.get_width() - 10, 10))
    WIN.blit(yellow_health_text, (10, 10))
                                  
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (red.x, red.y))
    
    for bullet in REDbullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, bullet)
        
    for bullet in YELLOWbullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, bullet)
    
    pygame.display.update()

def yellowmovement(keys_pressed, yellow):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x - VEL > 0: #left
        yellow.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and yellow.x + VEL + yellow.width < BORDER.x: #right
        yellow.x += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and yellow.y - VEL > 0: #up
        yellow.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and yellow.y + 10 + VEL + yellow.height < HEIGHT: #down
        yellow.y += VEL   
    
def redmovement(keys_pressed, yellow):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and red.x - VEL -5 > BORDER.x +BORDER.width : #left
        red.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and red.x + VEL + red.width -15 < WIDTH: #right
        red.x += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and red.y - VEL > 0: #up
        red.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and red.y + 10 + VEL + red.height < HEIGHT: #down
        red.y += VEL 
    
def draw_winner(text):
    draw_text = WINNER_FONT.render(text, 1, WHITE)
    WIN.blit(draw_text, (WIDTH/2 - draw_text.get_width() /
                         2, HEIGHT/2 - draw_text.get_height()/2))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(5000)

def bulletscontrol(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red):
    for bullet in YELLOWbullets:
        bullet.x += BULLETspeed
        if red.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(REDhit))
            YELLOWbullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x > WIDTH:
            YELLOWbullets.remove(bullet)

    for bullet in REDbullets:
        bullet.x -= BULLETspeed
        if yellow.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(YELLOWhit))
            REDbullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x < 0:
            REDbullets.remove(bullet)    

def main():
    global REDhealth
    global YELLOWhealth
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL and len(YELLOWbullets) < BULLETnum:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        yellow.x + yellow.width, yellow.y + yellow.height//2 -2, 10, 5)
                    YELLOWbullets.append(bullet)
                    
                if event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL and len(REDbullets) < BULLETnum:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        red.x, red.y + red.height//2 -2, 10, 5)
                    REDbullets.append(bullet)
                    
            if event.type == REDhit:
                REDhealth -= 1


            if event.type == YELLOWhit:
                YELLOWhealth -= 1
                
        winner_text = ""
        if REDhealth <= 0:
            winner_text = "Yellow Wins!"

        if YELLOWhealth <= 0:
            winner_text = "Red Wins!"

        if winner_text != "":
            draw_winner(winner_text)
            break
            
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        redmovement(keys_pressed, red)
        yellowmovement(keys_pressed, yellow)
        
        bulletscontrol(YELLOWbullets, REDbullets, yellow, red)
        
        draw_window(red, yellow, YELLOWbullets, REDbullets, REDhealth, YELLOWhealth)        
         
        main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code gives a syntax error after roughly 30 seconds:

```
  File "c:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\Helllo.py", line 161, in main
    draw_window(red, yellow, YELLOWbullets, REDbullets, REDhealth, YELLOWhealth)
  File "c:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\Helllo.py", line 52, in draw_window
    "Health: " + str(REDhealth), 1, WHITE)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object


PS C:\Users\chris>
```

Does anyone know what this error is and why it is happening? Thanks

Comment: It's because your `main()` function calls itself unconditionally. Just delete the call to `main()` from the end of the loop - it's already in a loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling `main` function inside the `while` loop.

So every frame, you are calling `main` function. Which if you call it a bunch of time, will trigger the recursion limit error.